# how do i destroy a DontDestroyOnLoad Gameobject

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I have a **DontDestroyOnLoad** Gameobject and i just can't destroy it I have tried a lot of things.

```
private void Awake()
    {

        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;

        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
        void Start()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<audiomanager>().Play("rain");

    }
```

I have tried destroying it from another script through

```
Destroy(GameObject.Find("rainmanager"));
```

and

```
Destroy(rainmanager.instance.gameObject);
```

it just doesn't get destroyed, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was my fault all along, I have been looking for the solution for hours now, but I made 2 mistakes. Firstly I created a duplicte of the dontdestroyonload object in another scene, so even when the original was getting deleted i thought it wasn't.

```
Destroy(GameObject.Find("rainmanager"));
```

The method above doesn't work maybe because I should be destroying the instance.

```
Destroy(rainmanager.instance.gameObject);
```

this method does work.